# Why requestLocationUpdates listener is not called after reboot or force close?

Tags: android, location

after the phone reboot or the app force close the listener that i set in locationManger.requestLocationUpdates is not called. do i have to  to keep track of my location broadcast receiver and register it again when the app is open and when i get boot broadcast ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do i have to to keep track of my location broadcast receiver and
>   register it again when the app is open and when i get boot broadcast ?

Not sure what you mean "register it again"... You write the code once, and it will register when your app starts. Of course the locationManager you've instantiated will disappear when your app's process dies...

Comment: by register it again i ment call "locationManger.requestLocationUpdates". And the app could receive broadcasted event even when the process dies (like android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED) in BroadcastReceiver, why this is not the case for location update ?

Comment: No, if you app isn't running then BOOT_COMPLETED won't help you. You could set a component of your app to start up once the boot is completed by adding this to your manifest, and then listening for location updates from there. But somehow, some way, you first need to get something of your app running.